# Trying to scrape this website and the code is returning an empty csv - PYTHON Scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

Trying to scrape this website and the code is returning an empty csv - PYTHON Scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class Articulo(Item): 
    titulo = Field()
    precio = Field()
    descripcion = Field()

class MercadolibreCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'El Bosquimano'
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20
    }

    download_delay = 1  

    allowed_domains = ['listado.mercadolibre.com.ar','articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar'] 
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/sillon#D[A:sillon,L:undefined]'] 

    rules = ( 

        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/_Desde_\d+'
            ),follow=True 
        ),
        
        Rule(
             LinkExtractor( 
                 allow=r'/MLA-' 
             ), follow=True, callback='parse_items'
        ),
    )

def limpiartexto(self, texto):
    nuevotexto = texto.replace('\n','').replace('\n,').replace('\t','').strip()
    return nuevotexto


def parse_items(self,response): 
    item = ItemLoader(Articulo(),response)    
    item.add_xpath('titulo','//h1[@class="item-title__primary "]/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiartexto))
    item.add_xpath('descripcion','//div[@class="ui-pdp-description"]/p/text()') 
    item.add_xpath('precio','//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]/text()')
yield item.load_item()
```

Well the code when i execute it in pycharm using the command "scrapy runspider namefile.py -o namecsv.csv -t csv", it returns an csv blank
So i believe the problem is in the parse_items code, specifically in the xpath of the website, but i dont know why and what should i use.

Website: https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-738462581-sillon-stylo-3-cuerpos-tela-chenille-o-antidesgarro--_JM#position=1&type=item&tracking_id=0dd5c51d-4c3b-4f3a-87e6-cbdd6eaf4796
From there i want to get the title, the price (only numbers) and the description.

Im a noob and i will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is mostly correct. There are just some indentation issues in the `MercadolibreCrawler()` class. Here's how it should be indented:

```py
class MercadolibreCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'El Bosquimano'
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20
    }

    download_delay = 1  

    allowed_domains = ['listado.mercadolibre.com.ar','articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar'] 
    start_urls = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ar/sillon#D[A:sillon,L:undefined]'] 

    rules = ( 

        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r'/_Desde_\d+'
            ),follow=True 
        ),
        
        Rule(
             LinkExtractor( 
                 allow=r'/MLA-' 
             ), follow=True, callback='parse_items'
        ),
    )

    def limpiartexto(self, texto):
        nuevotexto = texto.replace('\n','').replace('\n,').replace('\t','').strip()
        return nuevotexto


    def parse_items(self,response): 
        item = ItemLoader(Articulo(),response)    
        item.add_xpath('titulo','//h1[@class="item-title__primary "]/text()', MapCompose(self.limpiartexto))
        item.add_xpath('descripcion','//div[@class="ui-pdp-description"]/p/text()') 
        item.add_xpath('precio','//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]/text()')
        yield item.load_item()
```

For `limpiartexto()` and `parse_items()` to be part of the `MercadolibreCrawler()` class, they have to be indented one level to the right of the `class MercadolibreCrawler(CrawlSpider):` line. Similarly, to be part of the `parse_items()` function, `yield item.load_item()` should be indented one level to the right of the `def parse_items(self,response):` line.

Running the code above should give you a CSV with the description and price, but there is an issue with the title. On the webpage you provided, the title is written like this:

```html
<h1 class="ui-pdp-title">¡¡sillon Stylo 3 Cuerpos Tela Chenille O Antidesgarro ¡¡</h1>
```

So we can rewrite the title's `add_xpath` call to look for the `ui-pdp-title` class:

```py
item.add_xpath('titulo','//h1[@class="ui-pdp-title"]/text()')
```

Our `parse_items()` function should now look like this:

```py
    def parse_items(self,response): 
        item = ItemLoader(Articulo(),response)    
        item.add_xpath('titulo','//h1[@class="ui-pdp-title"]/text()')
        item.add_xpath('descripcion','//div[@class="ui-pdp-description"]/p/text()') 
        item.add_xpath('precio','//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]/text()')
        yield item.load_item()
```

If you update that in your `MercadolibreCrawler()` class and re-run the script, you should get the title, description, and price saved to a CSV.